Excel API's raw_SaveCopyAs() method not working as expected
I want to save an .xlsx file and its copy after modifying content in sharepoint location using C++ code.
For the first time, I manually saved the file but for the sake of saving its copy, I used Excel API's SaveCopyAs() but I encountered the error:
Sorry, we couldn't find file. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?
I tried using lower level method like raw_SaveCopyAs() but returning hr code as 0x800A03EC but when I use SaveAs() or raw_SaveAs() I can successfully save the copy of the file in the same location.
I need to know the reason behind the failure of raw_SaveCopyAs().Or can I make this raw_SaveCopyAs() work?
Also tried in the following ways:-

URL contains spaces so encoded the url by replacing '%20' in place of spaces.
Checked for the network connections.
File in use is also not applicable since I am the only user saving both of them.

Thanks in advance!
